# Pyspark-SQL Sum Integer to Date (with sql)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to add any number of days to a given date, for example I want to add a day to today's date.

I have one dataframe like this:

```
------------
|   date   |
------------
|2020-10-01|
------------
```

I would like to get a dataframe like this:

```
------------
|   date   |
------------
|2020-10-02|
------------
```

The real code is incrusted in a complex sql query then the valid result is ONLY with SQL statements.

I have tried with this code, that try to get the next day of today and it's not working due to difference between types date and int, I think that I am looking for something similar to python timedelta but in pyspark-sql

```
spark.sql(f"SELECT to_date(now()) + 1")
```

The error:

```
cannot resolve '(to_date(current_timestamp()) + 1)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(to_date(current_timestamp()) + 1)' (date and int)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of searching I found a function that solves the problem:

```
spark.sql("SELECT date_add(to_date(now()),1)").show()
```

Documentation:

```
date_add(Column start, int days)
Returns the date that is days days after start
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html